# Resolve rgdal package failing on Travis build

Tags: r, travis-ci, spatial, gdal

I had used the `rgdal` R package in my Travis build successfully for about a year, with few issues.

With the recent deployment of version 1.4-2 of `rgdal` the - formerly passing - builds started to fail with message

```
In file included from inverser.c:5:0:   
/tmp/Rtmpysf7it/R.INSTALL748c54b7a89/rgdal/inst/include/projects.h:150:33: 
error: conflicting types for ‘projUV’  typedef struct { double u, v; } projUV;
                                 ^ 
In file included from inverser.c:3:0: /usr/include/proj_api.h:54:37:
 note: previous declaration of ‘projUV’ was here
     typedef struct { double u, v; } projUV;
```

I am unsure where the "old" proj_api.h comes from and how to remove it in a Travis environment.

My travis.yml config is the following:

```
language: r
dist: trusty
sudo: false

cache:
  packages: yes

r_packages:
  - testthat
  - roxygen2
  - covr

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - gdal-bin
      - proj-bin
      - libgdal-dev
      - libgdal1-dev
      - libproj-dev
      - libgeos-dev
      - r-cran-ncdf4
      - libv8-3.14-dev
      - libprotobuf-dev
      - protobuf-compiler
      - libudunits2-dev
      - libnetcdf-dev
      - libjq-dev

before_install:
    - sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
    - sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:opencpu/jq
    - sudo apt-get --yes --force-yes update -qq

after_success:
  - Rscript -e 'covr::coveralls()'
```

Any advice on how to resolve this issue is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify how you can tell Travis to install from R-Forge, as Edzer and Roger have suggested.  I believe you can add the following anywhere in your `.travis.yml`:

```
repos: 
  CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com
  rforge: http://R-Forge.R-project.org
```

See [Travis R configuration docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/#miscellaneous) for details.

Alternately you could literally run the R command in a `before_install` block, like so:

```
before_install:
  - R -e 'install.packages("rgdal", repos=c("http://R-Forge.R-project.org", "http://cran.rstudio.com"))'
```

which is maybe a bit more obvious if less tidy.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is much preferable to downgrading rgdal via `Remotes:`, as it happens entirely at Travis level, and does not involve tweaking the DESCRIPTION file

Answer (score 2):

Answer 2 is the correct answer. I am the rgdal maintainer, and have answered this question authoritatively on mail and twitter. When enough users of outdated PROJ versions (pre 4.9.3, so before September 2016) have confirmed that 1.4-3 resolves their problems, I'll submit 1.4-3 to CRAN. I do not and never will follow SO, but had you done the right thing and posted to R-sig-geo, you would have got my attention.

I advise putting substantial pressure on any systems still using PROJ 4.8.0 to upgrade. That version was published 13 March 2012, so has its 7th birthday today, and really deserves to have its bits recycled.

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving this issue would be to use an older version of `rgdal`. To install a specific version of the `rgdal` package you can add the following line to the  `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Remotes: cran/rgdal@1.3-9
```

This will install and use the previous version (1.3-9), the one released before 1.4-2. This worked for me at least.

Got the idea from here: https://travis-ci.community/t/travis-build-ignoring-r-package-version-in-description/2431/2

Comment: The other option is to install the dev version from r-forge where the issue has been addressed, by `install.packages("rgdal", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

Comment: And to the poster of the answer: this message does not imply that rgdal requires PROJ 6, but only that it'll work with it. It requires PROJ >= 4.8.0, as the CRAN landing page declares.

Comment: How do you indicate to install the dev version from r-forge in `.travis.yml`?

Comment: @jtr13 I believe you want to add this to .travis.yml: 
    repos:
      CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com
      rforge: http://R-Forge.R-project.org

Or just add Edzer's command in a `before_install()` section, though you may need to also include the CRAN repo so `rgdal` can install the `sp` dependency. (Ugh can't do newlines in comments, posting this as an answer below instead)

Comment: @EdzerPebesma: I see. For some reason I interpreted the sentence "from 1.4.1 'rgdal" will build and function when' PROJ '> = 6 " to mean that `proj` must be larger than 6.0. Will edit.